# PostgreSQL Trigger and Notification Function Not Working as Expected

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

**Question:**

I have set up a PostgreSQL function and triggers to send notifications when there are `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` operations on the `RiderDataPosition` table. However, despite my efforts, I'm not receiving any notifications as expected. I'm seeking guidance on troubleshooting this issue. My end result would be that I would like to get a notification when something in the `RiderDataPosition` table changes.

**UPDATE**

When sending a query `NOTIFY RiderPositionUpdate` to the database, my test application receives a response. That means something is going wrong with the trigger!

**Problem Description:**

I have a PostgreSQL database running in a Docker container, and I'm using the latest version. The goal is to send notifications to the `RiderPositionUpdate` channel whenever there's a change in the `RiderDataPosition` table. Here's what I've done so far:

1. **Notification Function:**

   I've created a notification function as follows:

   ```sql
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "TrackSolutionsCore".notify_rider_position_change()
   RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
   BEGIN
       IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
           PERFORM pg_notify('RiderPositionUpdate', json_build_object('operation', 'insert', 'record_id', NEW."TransponderId")::text);
           RAISE NOTICE 'Inserted record with TransponderId %', NEW."TransponderId";
           RETURN NEW;
       ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
           PERFORM pg_notify('RiderPositionUpdate', json_build_object('operation', 'update', 'record_id', NEW."TransponderId")::text);
           RAISE NOTICE 'Updated record with TransponderId %', NEW."TransponderId";
           RETURN NEW;
       ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
           PERFORM pg_notify('RiderPositionUpdate', json_build_object('operation', 'delete', 'record_id', OLD."TransponderId")::text);
           RAISE NOTICE 'Deleted record with TransponderId %', OLD."TransponderId";
           RETURN OLD;
       END IF;
   END;
   $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
   ```
2. **Triggers:**

   I've created triggers for `AFTER INSERT`, `AFTER UPDATE`, and `AFTER DELETE` operations on the `RiderDataPosition` table. Here's an example of one of those triggers:

   ```sql
   CREATE TRIGGER rider_data_position_insert_trigger
   AFTER INSERT ON "TrackSolutionsCore"."RiderDataPosition"
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE FUNCTION "TrackSolutionsCore".notify_rider_position_change();
   ```
3. **Table Structure:**

   The `RiderDataPosition` table has the following structure:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE "RiderDataPosition"
   (
       "TransponderId" integer generated by default as identity
           constraint "PK_RiderDataPosition"
               primary key,
       -- Other columns...
   );
   ```

**Issues Faced:**

Despite setting up these triggers and the notification function, I'm not receiving any notifications on the `RiderPositionUpdate` channel when I perform CRUD operations on the `RiderDataPosition` table. I've attempted to receive these notifications through a C# application using the `NotificationEventHandler` and directly via DataGrip by executing `LISTEN "RiderPositionUpdate"` in the console, but neither approach yields results.

**Environment:**

- PostgreSQL version: [16]
- Docker Engine: [v24.0.6]

**Test Application**

```
using Npgsql;

var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("connectionString");
conn.Open();
conn.Notification += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine("Received notification");

using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("LISTEN RiderPositionUpdate", conn)) {
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

while (true) {
    conn.Wait();   // Thread will block here
}
```

**Output in DataGrip after inserting a new record into the table**

[image: SQL Query Response]

**Question:**

1. What could be causing this issue, and how can I troubleshoot it further?
2. Are there any specific PostgreSQL configurations or Docker settings I should check to ensure that notifications work correctly?
3. Is there a way to verify that notifications are being sent by the triggers and function, perhaps through PostgreSQL logs or a different method?
4. Are there any common pitfalls or mistakes in setting up PostgreSQL triggers and notification functions that I might be overlooking?

Any insights or guidance on how to diagnose and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you commit the transaction?

Comment: Doesn't that automatically happen since the transaction is already being sent due to inserting a new record?

Comment: On the command line, yes. But there are people who disable autocommit, so I thought I'd better ask. Can you see the modified rows in a second session?

Comment: Yes, I can see the modified rows in a second session!

Comment: Well, add a `RAISE NOTICE` in the trigger function to check if it is running. Is there a listener for that channel?

Comment: I added the `RAISE NOTICE` and when executing an insert statement it's being logged fine. What do you mean by if there is a listener for that channel? Do you mean an application that is listening to that channel to see if notifications are being sent properly? I added a test application that shows how I am currently listening for notifications to my question!

Comment: Thanks. I see no `LISTEN` statement in the test application.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, this might sound a bit stupid, but what do you mean you don't see a LISTEN statement in the test application? Doesn't `conn.Notification += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine("Received notification");` sent a console writeline the moment it receives a notification?

Comment: `NOTIFY RiderPositionUpdate` seems to trigger my test application, so something is going wrong with the trigger itself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a case mismatch.  If your channel name contains real capital letters, that name must be enclosed in double quotes in your LISTEN command.  Your NOTIFY command works with your LISTEN, as it case-folds the channel name same as LISTEN does, while pg_notify does not case-field its first argument so it doesn't work.

But better yet, change your channel name so it doesn't have capital letters in it.